# LISP - removing an element from a list with nested lists

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I need to remove an element from a list which contain inner lists inside. The predefined element should be removed from every inner list too.

I have started working with the following code:

```
(SETQ L2 '(a b ( a 2 b) c 1 2 (D b (a s 4 2) c 1 2 a) a )) ; defined my list 

; Created a function for element removing
(defun elimina (x l &optional l0)
(cond (( null l)(reverse l0))
((eq x (car l))(elimina x (cdr l) l0))
(T (elimina x (cdr l) (cons (car l) l0))))
)

(ELIMINA 'a L2)
```

But unfortunately it removes only elements outside the nested lists.

I have tried to create an additional function which will remove the element from the inner lists.

```
(defun elimina-all (x l)
(cond ((LISTP (CAR L))(reverse l)(elimina x (car l)))
(T (elimina-all  x (CDR L)))
)
)
```

but still unsuccessfully.

Can you please help me to work it out?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this homework? If yes please add the tag homework.

Comment: you should also indent your code correctly. As it is now it is difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
(defun elimina (x l &optional l0)
  (cond ((null l) (reverse l0))
        ((eq x (car l)) (elimina x (cdr l) l0))
        (T (elimina x (cdr l) (cons (if (not (atom (car l))) 
                                        (elimina x (car l)) 
                                        (car l))
                                     l0)))))
```

Comment: This is a good solution, thank you, but it doesn't work on removing a set of elements from  list for example:

    (ELIMINA (a 2 b) L2)

Comment: In that case you'd need to replace `(eq x (car l))` with `(if (atom x) (eq x (car l)) (member (car l) x))`.

Comment: Using a `(member (car l) x)` will remove only the first member of a list from the whole list. But actually the point is to remove `(A 2 B)` from `(A (A (A 2 B)))` list (L2).

Comment: I see so instead replace `(eq x (car l))` with `(equals x (car l))`; deep comparison rather than reference equality.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd suggest you read this book, at least, [this page](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html), it explains (and also gives very good examples!) of how to traverse a tree, but most importantly, of how to combine functions to leverage more complex tasks from more simple tasks.

```
;; Note that this function is very similar to the built-in
;; `remove-if' function. Normally, you won't write this yourself
(defun remove-if-tree (tree predicate)
  (cond
    ((null tree) nil)
    ((funcall predicate (car tree))
     (remove-if-tree (cdr tree) predicate))
    ((listp (car tree))
     (cons (remove-if-tree (car tree) predicate)
           (remove-if-tree (cdr tree) predicate)))
    (t (cons (car tree)
             (remove-if-tree (cdr tree) predicate)))))

;; Note that the case of the symbol names doesn't matter
;; with the default settings of the reader table. I.e. `D' and `d'
;; are the same symbol, both uppercase.
;; Either use \ (backslash) or || (pipes
;; around the symbol name to preserve the case. Eg. \d is the
;; lowercase `d'. Similarly, |d| is a lowercase `d'.
(format t "result: ~s~&"
        (remove-if-tree
         '(a b (a 2 b) c 1 2 (D b (a s 4 2) c 1 2 a) a)
         #'(lambda (x) (or (equal 1 x) (equal x 'a)))))
```

Here's a short example of one way to approaching the problem. Read the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same answer as you and, unfortunately, I couldn't completely understand the answers above so I just worked on it and finally I got a really simple function in Lisp that does exactly what you want.

```
(defun remove (a l)
(cond
    ((null l) ())
        ((listp (car l))(cons (remove a (car l))(remove a (cdr l))))
        ((eq (car l) a) (remove a (cdr l)))
        (t (cons (car l) (remove a (cdr l))))
        )
    )
```

The function begins with two simple cases, which are: 'list is null' and 'first element is a list'. Following this you will "magically" get the `car` of the list and the `cdr` of the list without the given element. To fixed that up to be the answer for the whole list you just have to put them together using `cons`.